# Bad time format string when I use TimeValue() on a DateTime object where date separator is a dot

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

It seems that Crystal Reports doesn't like the "." as a date separator. For example, line like this will cause a "Bad time format string" error.

```
TimeValue("04.12.2013 4:17PM")
```

However, the following is fine.

```
TimeValue("04-12-2013 4:17PM")
```

Anyone know a way for me to get around this problem? I just want to take a DateTime and isolate the time portion of it. Considering "." is actually a valid date separator for some countries (ex: Norway)

Similar issue with DateValue("04.12.2013 4:17PM") will cause error "Bad date format string"

Thanks!

Comment: Replace the dots with dashes before using TimeValue.

Comment: Interesting, it got me thinking. For DateValue(), we can then replace dots with dashes before using DateValue() and then afterwards, replace the dashes with dots. Feels kinda hacky though.

Comment: It does, doesn't it....you could always convert to string and then do Left(), Mid(), Right()?